# Перевести с паскаля на питон

Tags: python, pascal

Pascal:

```
i:=1;
while i<=n do
 if a[i] mod c=0 then
 begin
  n:=n+1;
  for j:=n downto i+1 do
  a[j]:=a[j-1];
  a[i]:=m;
  i:=i+2;
 end
 else i:=i+1;
```

Не очень разбираюсь в особенность паскаля, поэтому просто мог сделать прямой перевод:

```
n = int(input())
c = int(input())
a = list(map(int,input().split()))
i = 1
while i <= n:
    if a[i] % c == 0:
        n += 1
        for j in range(n,i+1,-1):
            a[j] = a[j-1]
            a[i] = c
            i += 2
    else:
        i += 1
```

Он не работает:

> a[j] = a[j-1] IndexError: list index out of range

Т.к я понимаю `j` принимает значение > `n-1`, что связано с каким-нибудь другим устройством списков в pascal.

Мой полный код

```
n = int(input())
c = int(input())
a = list(map(int,input().split()))
i = 0
while i < n:
    if a[i] % c == 0:
        n += 1
        for j in range(n-2,i+1,-1):
            a[j] = a[j-1]
        a[i] = c
        i += 2
    else:
        i += 1
print(*a)
```

Comment: В питоне позитивная индексация начинается с 0, а не с 1. И заканчивается соответственно на n.

Comment: Единственное отличие Паскаля от нормальных языков (и Питона) состоит в данном плане в том, что его массивы по умолчанию индексируются с единицы.

Answer (score 1):

У вас в коде две ошибки.  Первая, как упомянули коллеги в комментариях,
в том, что в *Python* списки индексируются, увы, с нуля.  Так что:

```python
i = 0
while i < n:
```

Вторая в том, что в вашем паскалевом коде тело цикла состоит только из
одной инструкции, а в пайтоновом — из трёх.  Так
что:

```python
        for j in range(n - 1, i, -1):
            a[j] = a[j-1]
        a[i] = c
        i += 2
```

---

```python
c = 2
a = [42, 50, 76, 84, 100]
i = 0
while i < len(a):
    if a[i] % c == 0:
        a.insert(i, c)
        i += 2
    else:
        i += 1
print(*a)
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но ошибка сохранилась File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    a[j] = a[j-1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Mikey_mouse  Приведите пример входных данных?  Скорее всего в `range` дело.

Comment: Опубликовал сверху мой полный код который я тестирую, вот входные данные: n = 5    ,  c =  2,
a = 42 50 76 84 100

Comment: @Mikey_mouse `for j in range(n-1, i + 1, -1)` Есть простой способ проверки: подставляете крайние значения счетчика в формулу. Должно быть все корректно. У вас выход за границу массива при `j=n`

Comment: @Mikey_mouse  См. правку.

Comment: @Ainar-G так можно но в том то и задача, что сделать нужно сдвигами